# Am I blacklisted in Singapore?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore, denial-of-entry

I am an Indian and use to do on-job training in Singapore in 2014, I had 6 month work pass but left the job after 3 month without telling my employers.

Am I blacklisted to enter Singapore on a tourist visa for 4 days maximum?

Comment: How soon after leaving your job did you exit Singapore?

Comment: Did you pay any income tax obligations that you had outstanding? Otherwise, you could get into trouble for not paying all your taxes.

Answer (score 10):

**No**, because you have not stayed or worked in Singapore illegally.  It's not a crime to stop working and return home.

This assumes that you left Singapore before the validity of your visa ended.  If your employer cancelled your Work Pass (as I presume they did), you had 30 days from that date to leave the country.

Comment: "It's not a crime to stop working and return home."  Interesting, yer quite sure that's the case in Singapore?  (In, say, *Australia* - for goodness sake - in that essential situation (a company sponsors you to work for them in Aus, and you "bust" them and run off home) you do indeed get "in trouble" from the authorities and it's (some sort of) black mark against you visa-wise in the future.)

Comment: @Fattie I don't believe that's the case for Australia either, but if you have references that say otherwise, let's see them.

Answer (score 3):

The visitor visa is handled by ICA (Immigrations and Checkpoint Authority) and work pass is handled by MoM (Ministry of Manpower). Leaving early without informing won't cause any adverse issue in future visits. Provided, you settled all the dues including taxes and bills.

However, if you apply for pass again to work in Singapore, this abandonment will be considered.

If questioned in border about this, answer truthfully and at the same time, do not volunteer information. Just give answer to questions asked. You will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not a great thing to just leave without letting know (I guess you must have had your reasons), but no, you will not be blacklisted for that. You could be rather blacklisted for an overstay which ICA is very particular about, but not for leaving to early. 
Also to add on: When it comes to employment, Ministry of Manpower (MOM) is the body that deals with these kind of issues, not ICA. 
Hope that clarifies :)